# R: How to display NA values in excel when using WriteXLS?

Tags: r, excel, export-to-excel

I have a data frame, with some of the values being NA. When I tried to export the data frame to excel using WriteXLS package, the NA values disappeared (but not the NaN values). Is there a way to explicitly display "NA" in the spreadsheet for my NA values?

A workable example can be

```
x <- c(NA, 8, 5) 
l <- c("ab", "cd", "ef") 
s <- c(8, NA, 5) 
df = data.frame(x, l, s)   
write.xlsx(df,"path/to/file/test.xlsx")
```

Thank you very much!

Edited: I originally asked about the usage of the package WriteXLS, since I didn't want to install two packages (rJava+xlsx), I got WriteXLS. However, I think somebody else using xlsx will benefit from  @PavoDive's answer, so I'll just add the following example data frame

```
x <- c(NA, 8, 5) 
l <- c("ab", "cd", "ef") 
s <- c(8, NA, 5) 
df = data.frame(x, l, s) 
library(WriteXLS)
WriteXLS("df", "df.xls")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set to `TRUE` the `showNA` argument:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(df,"path/to/file/test.xlsx",append=T,showNA=T)
```